# How do you make function with any number of arguments with a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example i have

```
function passConcatenatedStringBack(){
  var i,concatString;
  for(i=0; i<arguments.length;i++){
    concatString = arguments[i];
  }
  callback(concatString); // this will be error since callback is undefined
}
```

How do I implement this in node callback style? Without using promises

Comment: And how do you pass a callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function passConcatenatedStringBack(){
  var i,concatString, error;
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); //convert to Array as Kenichi Shibata pointed out
  var callback = args.pop(); //get the callback function and remove it from the arguments.

  for(i=0; i< args.length;i++){
    concatString += args[i];
  }
  callback(error, concatString);
}
```

Just take the last argument and use it as the callback.
You should still implement validations for checking if the user provided a valid callback.

Comment: this looks good but node style callback is function a(arg1, ..., function(err,res){})

Comment: This will work the only problem is Array.pop(); will not work in this case because the arguments will be an [Object array] not Array
Please update accordingly :)

`var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);`
`var callback = args.pop();`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 1):

I would probably assume that the first argument is always a callback.

That way I would check if the first argument was of type function, if it is, then use that as a callback and use the rest as arguments for the function.

Well you could also, check if the last argument was a callback or not too.

Comment: You cannot assume that the first argument is the callback. The convention is the last argument is the callback

Answer (score 1):

The common way is to check if the last argument is a function:

```
function fn() {
  var cb = arguments.pop();

  if (typeof cb !== 'function') {
    throw new Error('No callback provided!');
  }

  // do your stuff and then callback
  cb(null, result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
function passConcatenatedStringBack(callback){}

passConcatenatedStringBack(function (args1){ // callback stuff });
```